# How to weight objects depending of demand / rarity

Tags: statistics

I hope the Mathematical site is the best place to ask my question.
I spend my afternoon thinking of a problem and I did not find any way to solve it mathematically.

I want to assign a value of an object based on rarity/demand of it. 
Here is what I got in mind :

There are 4 kinds of objects. A B C and D.
There are 30 people asking each for only one object.
Each object is composed of 10 parts.

People are randomly gathering only one part of any object everyday.

The idea is to quantify the value of each part of objects to be able to say : 
"You gave me 'a' parts of the A object, 'b' parts of the B object, 'c' parts of the C object and 'd' parts of the D object. The total value of the whole thing is equal to a complete A object".

To apply this, here is an example :

There are 30 people.

- 12 people want the object A
- 8 people want the object B.
- 7 people want the object C
- 3 people want the object D.

What would be the value of each part of each object displaying the fact that 12 people want the A object and only 3 the D and you still can't choose which object you will gather every day?

I hope I am in the right place to ask this kind of question, I can made my mind on how to do this properly

Answer (score 0):

The value should be directly proportional to the demand. So the value of the objects could be:

- A: $1200$ gold
- B: $800$ gold
- C: $700$ gold
- D: $300$ gold

If in that game (it's a game, isn't it?) there is no currency, simply imagine that there is one, but you don't have any and must pay with parts of the objects.

Does this answer yor question?

Besides of this simple solution there can be other factors involved. For example: if anybody gets the object, does he win the game? Or the game is rather cooperative? Do people play at the same time in a party? Or is it an open party and your probability of getting things is proportional to the time you spend playing? Etc.